# Elmah not logging IIS errors

Tags: asp.net, iis, elmah

I installed ELMAH and am testing it out with some errors.

I have two types of custom redirects on my site, one for asp.net and one for IIS (so I handle both www.domain.com/test.aspx and www.domain.com/test).

However ELMAH is only logging the .aspx error. Does ELMAH only log asp.net errors?

I added the HTTP handlers to both asp.net and IIS.

I know this isn't an ELMAH discussion site, but I am sure most of you use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have registered ELMAH as a regular http module under `<system.web>` then I'm pretty sure you'll get the behaviour you see right now. If you register it instead under `<system.webServer>` and have enabled Integrated Pipeline for the application pool (see Classic vs. Integrated Pipeline at http://forums.iis.net/t/1133307.aspx) presuming you are running IIS 7 or higher, then you should get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: I already did everything you said, still don't get it. Maybe it doesn't log that particular error? Any other way I can test it?

Comment: No, It still doesn't log them.